# Replace leading substring before a delimiter in all array keys

Tags: php, arrays, replace, key, prefix

I have an array like below.

```
$arr = Array ( [My_name] => Sam [My_location] => United_Kingdom [My_id] => 1 );
```

I'm trying to change the keys:

- from `My_name`, `My_Location`, `My_id`
- to `Your_name`, `Your_Location`, `Your_id`.

So the final array would look like

```
Array ( [Your_name] => Sam [Your_location] => United_Kingdom [Your_id] => 1 );
```

I was hoping something like `str_replace()` would work

```
 $arrnew = str_replace("My","Your",$arr);
```

But this is only replacing "My" to "Your" if "My" is a value, not a key.

So how would I change the keys?

Comment: The best option is probably to create your array with more generic keys such as `name`, `id`, and `location` in the first place

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`str_replace()` doesn't work on keys, so isolate the array keys as values then mutate them, re-combine the new keys with the original values.

```
$arrnew = array_combine(
    str_replace(
        "My",
        "Your",
        array_keys($arr)
    ),
    $arr
);
```

Answer (score 2):

you cannot change the keys in-place but you can do something like this:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    $arr[str_replace("My","Your",$key)] = $value;
    unset($arr[$key]);
}
```

This will add a new element with the new keys unsetting the old element

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    $newkey = str_replace("My","Your",$key);
    unset($arr[$key]);
    $arr[$newkey] = $val;
}
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/3vKkmAXx