# replace all keys in php array

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array:

```
['apple']['some code'] 
['beta']['other code']
['cat']['other code 2 ']
```

how can I replace all the "e" letters with "!" in the key name and keep the values
so that I will get something like that

```
['appl!']['some code'] 
['b!ta']['other code']
['cat']['other code 2 ']
```

I found this but because I don't have the same name for all keys I can't use It

```
$tags = array_map(function($tag) {
    return array(
        'name' => $tag['name'],
        'value' => $tag['url']
    );
}, $tags);
```

Comment: your array is not cleared, is it multidimensional or associative array please update your actual array

Comment: More generalized advice on changing keys: [Fastest way to add prefix to array keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2607595/2943403)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope your array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [apple] => some code
    [beta] => other code
    [cat] => other code 2 
)
```

If yes then you can do it like below:

```
$next_array = array();
foreach ($array as $key=>$val){
     $next_array[str_replace('e','!',$key)] = $val;
}
echo "<pre/>";print_r($next_array);
```

output:- https://3v4l.org/p9WFK

Answer (score 2):

Here we are using `array_walk` and through out the iteration we are replacing `e` to `!` in key and putting the key and value in a new array.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/780183)

```
<?php
$firstArray = array('apple'=>'some code','beta'=>'other code','cat'=>'other code 2 ');
$result=array();
array_walk($firstArray, function($value,$key) use (&$result) {
    $result[str_replace("e", "!", $key)]=$value;
});
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can stick with [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) actually. It is not really practical, but as a prove of concept, this can be done like this:

```
$array = array_combine(
    array_map(function ($key) {
        return str_replace('e', '!', $key);
    }, array_keys($array)),
    $array
);
```

We use [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) function to extract keys and feed them to [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). Then we use [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to put keys back to place.

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/97fc24eed1952aeb45d40a101e02466ba381b61d).

Comment: `str_replace()` can be called on arrays. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17764214/2943403

Answer (score 0):

If you got this :

```
$firstArray = array('apple'=>'some code','beta'=>'other code','cat'=>'other code 2 ');
```

You can try this :

```
$keys        = array_keys($firstArray);
$outputArray = array();
$length      = count($firstArray);

for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
{
    $key = str_replace("e", "!", $keys[ $i ]);
    $outputArray[ $key ] = $firstArray[$keys[$i]];
}
```

Comment: Replace `$outputArray[ $key ] = $firstAray[ $i ]` with `$outputArray[ $key ] = $firstArray[$keys[$i]]`

Answer (score 0):

We can iterate the `array` and mark all problematic keys to be changed. Check for the value whether it is string and if so, make sure the replacement is done if needed. If it is an `array` instead of a string, then call the `function` recursively for the inner `array`. When the values are resolved, do the key replacements and remove the bad keys. In your case pass `"e"` for `$old` and `"!"` for `$new`. (untested)

```
function replaceKeyValue(&$arr, $old, $new) {
    $itemsToRemove = array();
    $itemsToAdd = array();
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos($key, $old) !== false) {
            $itemsToRemove[]=$key;
            $itemsToAdd[]=str_replace($old,$new,$key);
        }
        if (is_string($value)) {
            if (strpos($value, $old) !== false) {
                $arr[$key] = str_replace($old, $new, $value);
            }
        } else if (is_array($value)) {
            $arr[$key] = replaceKeyValue($arr[$key], $old, $new);
        }
    }
    for ($index = 0; $index < count($itemsToRemove); $index++) {
        $arr[$itemsToAdd[$index]] = $itemsToRemove[$index];
        unset($arr[$itemsToRemove[$index]]);
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using just 2 lines of code:

**Given:**

```
$array
(
    [apple] => some code
    [beta] => other code
    [cat] => other code 2 
)
```

**Do:**

```
$replacedKeys = str_replace('e', '!', array_keys($array));
return array_combine($replacedKeys, $array);
```

**Explanation:**

`str_replace` can take an array and perform the replace on each entry. So..

1. `array_keys` will pull out the keys (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)
2. `str_replace` will perform the replacements (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)
3. `array_combine` will rebuild the array using the keys from the newly updated keys with the values from the original array (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

Comment: Posted many years earlier https://stackoverflow.com/a/17764214/2943403