# How can i sort the below array by index(Date)?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Please sort the below array by its index(date). I want to sort the below array by ASC order by its date. After sorting the first one will be 2020-06-29 and its array, then 2020-06-30, I have tried more sorting mechanism but it could not solve the issue. Please help me to sort out this issue

```
Array(
                 [2020-07-01] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [slot] => 09:00 AM-11:00 AM
                                [is_available] => 1
                                [slot_id] => 29
                            )
    
                    )
                [2020-06-29] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [slot] => 02:16 AM-02:16 AM
                                [is_available] => 1
                                [slot_id] => 14
                            )
    
                    )
    
                [2020-06-30] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [slot] => 09:00 AM-06:00 PM
                                [is_available] => 1
                                [slot_id] => 15
                            )
    
                    )
    
                [2020-07-02] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [slot] => 10:00 AM-05:00 PM
                                [is_available] => 1
                                [slot_id] => 35
                            )
    
                    )
    
                [2020-07-03] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [slot] => 10:00 AM-03:00 PM
                                [is_available] => 1
                                [slot_id] => 36
                            )
    
                    )
    
            )
```

Comment: have you tried my solution ? @Akhil Anand

Answer (score 1):

Try `ksort`

here is a short example :

```
<?php
$fruits = array("d"=>"lemon", "a"=>"orange", "b"=>"banana", "c"=>"apple");
ksort($fruits);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
?>
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

**EDIT :**

Since `ksort` seems to not be working, you should use `uksort`.

```
function date_compare($a, $b)
{
    $t1 = strtotime($a);
    $t2 = strtotime($b);
    return $t1 - $t2;
}    
uksort($data, 'date_compare');
```

here is a working example :

https://repl.it/repls/FoolhardyDrabPolygon

Comment: hint: 1) for demo purposes `var_dump()` or `print_r()` instead of printing loop would most likely perfectly suffice, 2) do not use `?>` unless you absolutely must.

Comment: It's just a working example, from the official php documentation, on how ksort works. Anyone should, of course, feel free to refactor the use of the function depending on their work habits or their needs

Comment: ksort not working on it. Here Date is treated as a string, and it is a multi-dimension array

Comment: is it still sorting by string comparaison ? If yes, try parsing the keys to Date. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541389/replace-all-keys-in-php-array

Comment: @AkhilAnand see my edit if `ksort` is still not working

Comment: Let me try this.

Comment: Well it's not in my working example, there's no reason it would not work. have a look

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Create a function which accepts two dates ( strings ) as parameters, this function returns 1 if first date is greater than the second, it returns -1 if second date > first date or 0 if date's are equal. Working of functions starts from Step 2.

Step 2 : Toeknize the strings to get respective year, month and day of the two dates respectively. [ see : https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php  ]

Step 3 : If first date's year > second date's year, return 1 . If second date's year > first date's year return -1, if they are equal proceed to Step 4.

Step 4 : If first date's month > second date's month, return 1 . If second date's month > first date's month return -1, if they are equal proceed to Step 5.

Step 5 : If first date's day > second date's day, return 1 . If second date's day > first date's day return -1, if they are equal return 0.

Now use php's usort function and pass your function in it

[see : https://www.php.net/usort ]